# Selecting MapPoint via ID

Tags: anychart

how can I activate a point on the map using the ID of a point?

I thought of something like "series.select(1234)" -> https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.core.map.series.Marker#select

But for example this code doesn't select any point on my map:

```
var series = map.marker(data);
series.select(2359);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've passed the wrong arguments to the select() method. In this case you should pass the array of indexes of the point to select, like

```
series.select([0, 1, 4]);
```

Also, you can take a look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/anycharts/4sn65L52/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found out my real problem was to use an ID instead of an index. How can I get the index of a point by an id? I tried something like this series.getPoint(id).getIndex() or series.getIndex(id) but that doesnt give me the index of the point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select point by an id or other field you should find index of this point in the data. Use [method "find" of data mapping](https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.data.Mapping#find).

```
var dataSet = anychart.data.set([
  {lat: -33.28, long: 135.58, id: 'myPoint'},
]);

var view = dataSet.mapAs();
var series = australiaMap.marker(view);

var index = view.find('id', 'myPoint');
series.select(index);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4sn65L52/3/